# How to avoid mysql primaryKey constraint Error

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql table.

- Requests - Request_id, Request_message

After user filling the Request_message in HTML form user clicks on submit button. I will generate a request ID from the requests table, and then add the row. (There are two hits to the table, one for getting the last request_id and one for add the row to the table). I want to avoid this.

Also, say at the same time 7-8 users hit the submit button, they will get the same last request_id from the table. they will add 1 to the last request_id, and tries to add the row. except one all are getting **primary key constraint error** .. How to avoid this ??

Please provide your suggestions.

Thanks
Devesh

Comment: Could you specify how are you getting the users to enter the data/strategy used in frontend? The id should be created with auto increment/ data inserted with transactions in this case

Answer (score 2):

Use [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for the primary key.

***Edit:***
If you don't use integer type for the column, then another solution is using row level lock.

Comment: I want to use the rquest_id is in the form of REQ0001, REQ0002 .....REQ0100......

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal Better would be to use numeric ID and just transform it for display.

Answer (score 0):

Use sp to insert the record in table.

or

Use auto number field for primary key in table.

or

use

```
 INSERTINTO request 
            (Request_id, 
             Request_message) 
VALUES      ( (SELECT 'REQ' + Lpad(Ifnull(Max(Request_id) + 1, 0), 4, 0) 
               FROM   request), 
              yourMessage)
```

Comment: I want to use the rquest_id is in the form of REQ0001, REQ0002 .....REQ0100......

Comment: In stored procedure create the next primary key to insert and then execute insert statement.

Comment: Yes Romil.. that is what i am doing. But it is possible that 4-5 users can get the same last request_id. (while one is generating next id other will get the same last id).. so at the time of adding the row in table they ill get primary_key constraint error.

Comment: @Devesh, I think you are not using Sp to fetch next PK.

Comment: refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html   Definition for you, Sp is set of statements that will be available to only one user at a time.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you can do something like that

```
INSERT INTO request (Request_id,Request_message) VALUES (
   (SELECT MAX(Request_id) FROM request), yourMessage)
```

or better, you can use the [autoincrement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for the p.k.

Moreover, if you demand all the increment/inserction problem to your DBMS, you can avoid directly problems related to p.k.

Comment: Its again nested query.. right?? Also Request_id is in the form of REQ0001, REQ0002....so i thin Max(Request_id+1) will not work....

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal If id's are REQxxyy, no it will not work, but you don't specify it into the question. Hovever mine answer (expect from the sql part) is sitll valid if you add a column that will contain an integer autoincremented that will be p.k.

Comment: But all the REQxxxx is different in the table. so i dont think of having an extra column just to AUTO_INCREMENT is  a good idea..becuase here REQuset_id is meant for PK only

Comment: Why not? If that will be p.k. i don't see where is the problem

Comment: Problem will be... 2 users endup adding same request_id in the table.

Comment: Told you: new column will be p.k. so that is new id. Then if you like to call it REQxxxx, you can add the first part of stirng "REQ" to your new colum value